# How to get the solr response into new page

Tags: php, solr

I'm learning about solr but there's too much ambiguity.

```
This is solr response:
http://94.229.169.64:8983/solr/collection1/search-en?q=craft%20base&wt=json
```

How to get content into the new page

I have tried to use the PHP Solarium but the response is not the same.

```
// create a client instance
$client = new Solarium_Client();

// get a select query instance
$query = $client->createSelect();

// set a query (all prices starting from 12)
$query->setQuery('craft base');

// set start and rows param (comparable to SQL limit) using fluent interface
$query->setStart(1)->setRows(20);

// set fields to fetch (this overrides the default setting 'all fields')
//$query->setFields(array('id','name','price'));

// sort the results by price ascending
$query->addSort('price', Solarium_Query_Select::SORT_ASC);

// this executes the query and returns the result
$resultset = $client->select($query);

// display the total number of documents found by solr
echo 'NumFound: '.$resultset->getNumFound(); // result = 182
```

but when you click the solr URL above, the result is 31.

Can you let me know how to get the solr response ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... sounds like your PHP client is making a slightly different request that returns more results somehow.

Try using a tool like wireshark to see exactly what kind of request your PHP page is making to the SOLR server.

http://www.wireshark.org/download.html

If you need more help after that post the request your PHP page makes to the SOLR server so we can compare and figure out the difference.

Comment: I have fixed this problem. The query default operator is OR so I have set it to AND.